# Why I fail to call web service like this?

Tags: java, soap, websphere

Backgroud : websphere 8.5 
Client jar: com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.5.0.jar
Client Error msg : WSWS3603E : Error:IllegalArgumentException : null parameter passed to the addTextNode method

I checked in google ,seems IBM websphere issue like below :
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM63658

But I still want run the service in local websphere. if any temp fix in my local machine?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of the fix in the link you provided.

> Applications that attempt to pass a null parameter value to the addTextNode method will now receive an IllegalArgumentException.

Instead of receiving a NullPointerException (the result before the fix you linked) you are receiving an IllegalArgumentException, which is expected when you pass in a null parameter.

One of the parameters you are passing to addTextNode is null.

Comment: Many params,let me try to figure out. Will contact you later.